# How can I hide particular element in react list?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to hide a particular element in react list.

This is how state looks like:

```
 this.state = {
    lgShow: false,
    list: [ 
      { id:1, hidden: true },
      { id:2, hidden: true }
    ]
  };
```

This is how component looks like:

```
  props.list.map( result => (
     <button onClick={toggle(result.id)}> Hide </button>
     { result.hidden && <div id={result.id}> .... </div>  }
  ))
```

I want to write function toggle which searches the id in App.js and change value of hidden for that id, something like this(Although I'm not able to setState() in this case).

```
 let toggle = id => {
    this.state.list.filter( val=>val.id===id ? val.hidden=!val.hidden )
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let toggle = id => {
  let newList = list.map(val => val.id === id ? { id: val.id, hidden: !val.hidden} : val);
  this.setState({list: newList})
}
```

You can do this inside toggle to `setState()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setState` method to update the state of `list`, that is the only way to update DOM in react. Every time a state/prop changes only then the DOM will re-render. This is how React works.

I have updated the `toggle` function, it now iterates over the `list` array, and toggle the `id` hidden flag passed in `toggle(id)` param.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lgShow: false,
      list: [ 
        { id:1, hidden: true },
        { id:2, hidden: true }
      ],
    };
  } // end of constructor
  
  toggle = (id) => {
    const list = this.state.list.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, hidden: !item.hidden }; 
      }
      return item;
    })
    this.setState({ list })
  } // end of toggle
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {list.map( result => (
          <>
            <button onClick={() => toggle(result.id)}> Hide </button>
            {result.hidden && <div id={result.id}>....</div>}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

P.S: I didn't run this code, just did a dry run on notepad.